# how to insert data into mysql database using spark java framework

Tags: mysql, angularjs, jsp

I am new to the spark java framework, how to insert the values into mysql database using sparkjava framework?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already read the data you want to insert into an RDD, You can use the following code to insert the records into database.

```
            rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String s) throws Exception {
                    //You Code to parse the String and insert the values into MYSQL.        
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on Shivanand's answer, you really want to use a foreachPartition as opposed to foreach.  With foreach, you will be opening a db connection for every element, as opposed to once per partition.  This is beneficial for a couple reasons, but most importantly its going to take sometime to open the connection.  That overhead will then be carried over for every element.  You will also be trying to open a lot of connections, and will probably make one of the admins pretty mad when they see potentially millions of db connection requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already read the file, then use the `foreachpartition` function. It will help you to insert it into MySQL.

Take Example-

```
rdd.foreachpartition(new VoidFunctioin<String> x)
{
  //Here make a connection enter code here
  public void call(Iterator<String> x)
  {
    Connection c=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("your conncetion name,localhost,dbname");
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
      String it=x.next();
      PreparedStatement ps=c.preparestatement("Insert into table_name (coln_name) values ("?")");
      ps.execute();    
    }
  }
});
```

It will insert it into MySQL.